# Combine filter and regex

Tags: jquery, regex, filter

I want to replace the content of a tag in brackets with a span

Example Text

```
<a href="#">Linkname [subtitle]</a>
```

Result should be

```
<a href="#">Linkname <span class="subtitle">subtitle</span></a>
```

What I have tried so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery( "a" )
        .contents()
        .filter(function(){
            return this.match(\[.*\]);
        })
    .wrap( "<span class='subtitle'></span>" );
});
```

But I am getting the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Comment: no matter how, if it is working at the end

Comment: this one http://regex101.com/r/wW5qU2/3

Comment: thanks the regex shure works fine, but I need the javascript part also, because this is dynamically generated content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
$('a').html(function(_,html){
   return html.replace(/\[(.+?)\]/g, "<span class='subtitle'>$1</span>");
});
```

Comment: Note : this rough solution delete the whole content of the A element and is OK only if you don't have any binding (which is probably the case here)

Comment: Thanks, I tried like this: `jquery('a)` but I receive error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (running Joomla 3 Template in Jquery non-conflict mode)

Comment: @dystroy by whole content what are you meaning? The contents won't be changed it's only getting replaced.

Comment: @Owl `jquery` or `jQuery`?

Comment: This is the code so far: `jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('a').html(function(html){
       return html.replace(/\[(.+?)\]/g, "<span class='subtitle'>$1</span>");
    });}); `

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need your function definition to be `function(i, html)` since the first argument passed to the function is the index of the element: [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function)

Comment: @AmitJoki If your a element contains other element on which you have bindings (or any state change, really), replacing the HTML make you lose them. If it's just some unbound text, then there's no problem.

Comment: @dystroy sort of getting it.. Thanks

Comment: ah ok, so in conclusion, it is better to use replace instead of trying to combine the filter with the regex?

Comment: yup, if you don't have any handlers which I don't suppose you have

Comment: @Owl If you just have some text in your `a` element, `replace` as shown here is the right solution. Just don't use this if you want to do replacements on a page or any big composite element.

Comment: Its for the main navigation on a Joomla site. Would this be too big?

Comment: For the Joomla site I decided to rather override the component and create the span class with str_replace, which should be the better option

Answer (score 0):

```
var re = /\[([^\]]*)\]/g;
var str = '<a href="#">Linkname [subtitle]</a>';
var subst = '<span class=\'$1\'>$1</span>"';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rA7aS3/4

Comment: It's a OK solution for many cases but note that this would replace the whole parent element, thus deleting all event bindings.

Comment: but I need the str link extracted dynamically from the html, therefore I was using jquery

Comment: var str = '' <- no this is not, I need to get the var str dynamically, sorry if bad explanation